# selectOneMenu with primefaces 2.2.1

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with p:selectOneMenu in primefaces 2.2.1.
I want to add a new component "selectoneMenu" into primefaces2.2.1.jar.
Any idea please.

Comment: I am using `h:selectOneMenu` with `styleClass="ui-widget ui-inputfield ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"`. That makes it look a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

The [`<p:selectOneMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) is introduced in [PrimeFaces 3.0](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf). It is **not** present in [PrimeFaces 2.2](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf).

So you have 2 options:

1. [Upgrade](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html) to PrimeFaces 3.0 (warning: it's still in development and not stable!)
2. Just use standard JSF [`<h:selectOneMenu>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneMenu.html).

Comment: I would say about PF 3, it's **very** unstable at the moment, as we experience lots of problems after migrating from version 2.